# Integral representation of $\psi^{(\nu)}(z)$ for $\nu>0$ but $\nu\not\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functions, gamma-function, polygamma

I need the integral representation of the polygamma function for $n>0$ but $n\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

I searched both among [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/) and [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/)

1. On Wolfram I found the representation of [$\psi^{(n+\frac{1}{2})}(z)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/03/01/02/0023/) with a mixture of summation and series.
2. I also found on Wolfram [some integral representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/07/01/01/), but trying to generate them gives me non-convergent integral (those involving the regularized gamma function $Q(a,0,z)$)
3. I also found one in which it is defined through a [boundary integral](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/07/02/0001/) but I don't know how to generate it.

In the 2nd point (the one with $Q(a,0,z)$) although "On the real axis " is written in the path, the problem is that the integral is done on complex values:

3° representation: since $t\in(0,1)\Rightarrow\ln(t)<0\Rightarrow \ln(t)^{\nu}\in\mathbb{C}$  (since $\nu>0$ and $\nu\not\in\mathbb{N}$)
4° representation: since $t\in(0,\infty)\Rightarrow -\ln(t+1)<0\Rightarrow (-\ln(t+1))^{\nu}\in\mathbb{C}$ (since $\nu>0$ and $\nu\not\in\mathbb{N}$)
5° representation: since $t\in(0,\infty)\Rightarrow -t<0 \Rightarrow (-t)^{\nu}\in\mathbb{C}$ (since $\nu>0$ and $\nu\not\in\mathbb{N}$)

I would need a representation that doesn't involve complex numbers though, i.e. something like this:
$$\psi^{(\nu)}(x)=\int_{a}^{b} f(\nu,t,x)\mathrm{d}t\qquad \text{where }(a,b)\subseteq\text{Domain}(f)$$

Can someone point me to some other site with useful formulas by chance?

Comment: The boundary integral probably is an [inverse Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem)

Comment: Also, even [Wolfram](https://functions.wolfram.com/Contribute/topten.html#6) is looking for a generalization for $\nu\in\Bbb R$, so how does one define this for $\psi^{(v)}(x)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Ah ok so the answer to my question doesn't exist yet ahahaha. But if I find the solution to any of the points on their list, how can I tell them?

Comment: There is an “email comments” button on the site

Comment: The most famous generalisation of the polygamma function is given by Espinosa and Moll in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305079.pdf. In Eq(5.2) they provide an integral representation as well.